# Design suggestion for Add / Edit scenario in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns, angularjs-scope

Here is my scenario. I have a addPersonController and editPersonController with addPersonView and editPersonView respectively. In both controller, I am uploading the Person's picture. My upload functionality uses scope variables / functions to handle file upload within controllers.  As a result I am end up with having same code in two different controller. Any suggestion how to reuse the upload functionality? I am using ng-flow directive to upload

```
$scope.personImageUploaderConfig = {
    target : '/personImageUpload',
    singleFile:true,
    chunkSize : $scope.maxChunkSize,
    query: function (flowFile, flowChunk) {
        // function will be called for every request
        return {
            personId: $scope.newPersonIdentifier, source: 'flow_query'
        };
    }
};   

$scope.onUploadCompleted = function () {
    //event triggers by ng-flow when upload completes
};

//calls by controller logic supplying personId
$scope.handleUpload = function(personId){       
    if($scope.personPicture){
        $scope.newPersonIdentifier = personId;
        $scope.image.flow.upload();         
    }
};
//event triggers by ng-flow when image selected
$scope.imageSelected= function () {

    else {

        $scope.getBinrayFromFile($scope.image.flow.files[0].file).then(function (binary) {
            $scope.personPicture = binary;
        });
    }
};

$scope.getBinrayFromFile=function(file){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onloadend = function(e){
        var data = e.target.result;
        deferred.resolve(data);
    };
    r.readAsBinaryString(file);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a directive to handle that, using `scope: false` to make scope in the directive be the same as the scope in the controller.